# Android Passing around Data across the App

Tags: android, persistent-storage

I have a listview which has a list of places - i have the id, name and position for each row of the listview. My data is stored locally in sqlite.

When a user clicks on a particular place i want to display the details of that particular place in the next Screen which is structured as follows

- A Fragment Activity that Host the two Fragments
- First Fragment has a Viewpager indicator on the top and information below that.
- Second Fragment hosts a Google Map that displays the place on the map.

So i will need to know the place that the user has selected in three different Activities and Fragments.

A user should be able to go back and choose a new place and that should again be able to be passed around.

**PlaceActivity.java which needs the ID of the Place**

```
public class PlaceActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
        OnShareTargetSelectedListener {

    private PlaceMapsFragment fragment_maps = null;
    private PlaceDetailsFragment fragment_details = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setTitle("Nandi Hills");
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tabMaps = actionBar.newTab();
        ActionBar.Tab tabDetails = actionBar.newTab();

        tabDetails.setText("Details");
        tabMaps.setText("Maps");

        tabDetails.setTabListener(new PlaceTabListener());
        tabMaps.setTabListener(new PlaceTabListener());

        actionBar.addTab(tabDetails);
        actionBar.addTab(tabMaps);

    }

    private class PlaceTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab,
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
            ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                    android.R.anim.fade_out);
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {

                if (fragment_details == null) {
                    fragment_details = new PlaceDetailsFragment();
                    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment_details,
                            PlaceDetailsFragment.TAG);
                } else {

                    ft.show(fragment_details);
                }
            } else {
                if (fragment_maps == null) {
                    // fragment_maps = new PlaceMapsFragment();
                    fragment_maps = PlaceMapsFragment.newInstance(new LatLng(
                            13.005621, 77.577531));
                    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment_maps,
                            PlaceMapsFragment.TAG);
                } else {

                    ft.show(fragment_maps);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                if (fragment_details != null) {
                    ft.hide(fragment_details);
                }
            } else {
                if (fragment_maps != null) {
                    ft.hide(fragment_maps);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a constructor in your MapFragment at takes in the values you need for that fragment then populate the fragment with that information.

```
public MyMapFragment(long id,String name,int position){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.position = position
}
```

You will need to set up a call back to the holding activity for the fragments to padd the information into the map fragment

if you need to send the data to an activity then include that data in the intent `intent.put("some_int",1);`

Comment: is it a good practice to set a static final variable in the listview activity and try to access it from every where ?

Comment: that would be fine yes because if you use loaders and multi-selection listview you need to have it global

Comment: MainActivity.java which hosts listview to PlaceActivity.java

Comment: Since i need the ID in three files - PlaceActivity, PlaceDetailsFragment and PlaceMapFragment

Comment: so just pass the ID to the activity in the intent and then have the `PlaceActivity` distribute it out to the fragments constructors assuming the `PlaceActivity` holds the 2 fragments

Comment: i have updated the question with my PlaceActivity Code. i need to getExtras here and then pass it to other two fragments it hosts ? or should i create a static final container here ?

Comment: Yes on the intent that starts that activity use `inent.putExtra(key,ID)` to send the id then in the `PlaceActivity` use the `getExtra` to get the value from the intent, have that activity hold the ID value then your fragments can access if from within that activity

Comment: thank you :D i was doing public static int place_pos = id in MainActivity :D